Factoring words with contractions
I'm supposed to factor data from a survey that includes a factor about arriving for appointments. The responses from that survey include "10 minutes early" "5 minutes early" "Precisely on time" "A few minutes late" and "I'm lucky to remember the appointment exists!" and blank responses ("")
So when I try to order them and factor them I've entered this:
factor_appointments <- factor(appointments, order = TRUE, 
   levels =c('10 minutes early','5 minutes early',
   'Precisely on time','A few minutes late',
    'I'm lucky to remember the appointment exists!', ''))
factor_appointments
summary(factor_appointments)

That returns an error:

Error: unexpected symbol in "factor_appointments <- factor(appointments, order = TRUE, levels =c('10 minutes early','5 minutes early','Precisely on time','A few minutes late','I'm"

I've figured out it's because the contraction in the word "I'm" makes it think a factor is 'I' followed by "m lucky to remember the appointment exists" because the coding uses '' to separate the levels so how do I get it to recognize I'm is not 'I' but a contraction word that's still part of the larger label?  If I simply remove the ' then it just counts zero instances of that response. If I leave it as is it returns an error.  What's the solution?

You can use double quotes:  levels = c("level1",  "I'm lucky .. ", "level3")

Or use backslash escapes - 'I\'m lucky .. '

There are (at least) three ways to handle strings containing quote characters (the first is probably easiest): see the help page ?Quotes for detailed information.

use double-quotes("") to delimit strings with single-quotes(') in them, and vice versa:

x <- c("I'm lucky", '"This is a quotation"')

(You'll see that this prints with a backslash protecting the double-quotes
[1] "I'm lucky"               "\"This is a quotation\""

unless you use print(x, quote = FALSE)
[1] I'm lucky             "This is a quotation"

). The backslash isn't really part of the string, it's just used in printing to distinguish it from the double-quotes delimiting the string ...

use a backslash (\) to 'protect' the quotation marks:

'I\'m lucky'

(this prints as "I'm lucky", i.e. delimited with double quotes)

raw strings

r'(I'm lucky)'

